# OctoberCMS Session unable to push

Tags: php, octobercms

I am creation OctoberCMS sessions using this thread https://octobercms.com/docs/services/session and I am trying to push my session but its not working. Here is my code (try).

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-request="{{ __SELF__ }}::onSessionCreate">Create Sessions</a>`

```
public function onSessionCreate(){
     $token = 'my token';
    $array = array(
                'id' => '500',
                'name'=>'sdfsd',
                'surname'  => 'zf'
    );
    
     \Session::put('user.token', $token);
     \Session::push('user.persons', $array);       
     
    $sessionData = \Session::get('user');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($sessionData);
    exit;

}
```

As you can see in my above code, I have `Create Session` button and On each click, I want to push my `person` session. But when I am printing my `session` , `print_r($sessionData);`  I am keep getting the same response with array..

```
Array
(
    [token] => my token
    [persons] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 500
                    [name] => sdfsd
                    [surname] => zf
                )

        )

)
```

Can someone guide me why I am unable to push my session array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm the problem is your code is `stopping execution in middle of the workflow`.

When you are working with `sessions` you need to let request finish instead `exiting in between`.

> Working Demo

**Your code section**

```php
function onSessionCreate(){
    $token = 'my token';
    $array = array(
        'id' => '500',
        'name'=>'name',
        'surname'  => 'surname'
    );
    
    \Session::put('user.token', $token);
    \Session::push('user.persons', $array);            
    return 'ok';
}    

function onGetSession() {
    $sessionData = \Session::get('user');
    return $sessionData;
}
```

**Your template section**

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-request="onSessionCreate">Create Sessions</a> <br/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-request="onGetSession">Get Sessions</a>
</div>
```

> **Result** - **click on below GIF to watch it in high quality.**

[image]

if any doubts please comment.